# value_counts() returns removed/filtered-out data in "Categorical" datatype in Pandas

Tags: pandas

Could someone please clarify me this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'years': [2015, 2016, 2017,2017, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020]})
df['years'] = df['years'].astype('category')

print(df.dtypes)
years    category
dtype: object
```

now, I create a new variable to subset the `years` column:

```
subset_years = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
```

then, filter the `years`:

```
subset_df = df[df['years'].isin(subset_years)]
print(subset_df)

   years
0   2015
1   2016
2   2017
3   2017
4   2018
```

now, I take the unique elements:

```
subset_df.years.unique()
```

and I get:

```
[2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
Categories (4, int64): [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
```

but, if I do `subset_df.years.value_counts()`, I get:

```
2015    1
2016    1
2017    2
2018    1
2019    0
2020    0
Name: years, dtype: int64
```

My question is that why does `subset_df.years.value_counts()` return `2019` and `2020` years and with count of `0` ? Since I already filter the `years`... was it not suppose to remove those `years` during subset/filter?

Could someone please clarify what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `2019` and `2020` are still within the categories. You can reset category before `value_counts` if you don't want filtered years to show up:

```
subset_df.years.cat.set_categories(subset_years).value_counts()
#2017    2
#2015    1
#2016    1
#2018    1
#Name: years, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation but still confused. Since `subset_df` should only have `[2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]` years because we filtered the data, why would `subset_df.years.value_counts()` consider showing `[2019, 2020]`? and why `unique()` did not consider? also, what do you mean by, `still within the categories`?

Comment: Because `years` is a category column, after filtering, the values change but `subset_df.years.cat.categories` doesn't change. `unique` check the values I believe, also specifically `value_counts` is not returning wrong result here. It's just including missing categories with zero count -